# Magento 2 - How to get product Manage Stock attribute value

Tags: magento2

I want to check is "Manage Stock" is set as Yes or No with specific product. Can anyone help us to get value of product "Manage Stock" attribute value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please place below code in any block file.

```
namespace Meetanshi\HelloWorld\Block;
class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_stockItemRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository $stockItemRepository,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_stockItemRepository = $stockItemRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getStockItem($productId)
    {
        return $this->_stockItemRepository->get($productId);
    }
}
?>
```

You can call getStockItem(YOUR_PRODUCT_ID) by passing product Id as parameter.

If you are placing above code in block than do it as below.

```
$id = YOUR_PRODUCT_ID;
$productStock = $block->getStockItem($id);
var_dump($productStock->getData());
```

You will get manage stock value of passing product.

Thanks

Comment: You are most welcome :)

Comment: this is the incorrect solution. You pass product Id as an argument to stockItemRepository, while it's expected to pass stock item id! You loaded stock item by item_id column from cataloginventory_stock_item table, not by product_id column

Answer (score 3):

You can get Manage Stock attribute value using stock registry.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$stockRegistry = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');

$stockItem=$stockRegistry->getStockItem($_product->getId());

echo $stockItem->getData('manage_stock');

echo $stockItem->getData('use_config_manage_stock');
```